# Storing CSS Tag Names in a Database for Data Driven Menu's ... is it wrong?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC. I have a project in which I am attempting to design a MVC TreeView menu system that is driven by records in the database. My Model looks like this:

```
public interface IMenuItemModel
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string ActionName { get; set; }
    string ControllerName { get; set; }
    string ParentName { get; set; }
    string ImageCssClassName { get; set; }
    string CssClassName { get; set; }
}
```

My view populates the menu items dynamically with Razor ...

```
<li class="navbar-left">
            <div class="menu-item-separator">

            </div>
            <div id="@item.Id" class="navbar-left menu-item">
                <i class="@item.ImageCssClassName"></i>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, item.ActionName, item.ControllerName)
                @GetDirectories(item)
         </div>
  </li>
```

My question is whether or not storing the CSS tagName of ANY item in the database is a violation of MVC or just a terrible hack idea to begin with? I'm not storing Markup anywhere outside of the View, I'm trying to stick to MVC conventions but I am wondering whether I'm going down a path of making something that is going to be a headache, violates principles and architecture, creates unnecessary points of failure and is basically an unmaintainable solution. Especially when storing something like CSS class names in a database... I don't know why, it just feels dirty.

I'm more or less using the Menu project as a means for testing data-driven design concepts in MVC to see what works and what does not, but I've reached a wall and I'm strongly doubting the success of a component like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicions serve you correctly; storing class names in the database is wrong - most of the time. There may be instances where storing a class name in a database (for instance if your site allowed its users to completely customise the look and feel of it by creating their own CSS or modifying class names) but judging by your question you're not storing class names in the database for this reason.

The database is designed for persisting data and class names are used for presentation. Generally creating a class or an id from a string that includes the record id is a better idea, like so:

`<i class="icon_@item.IconId"></i>` or `<i class="icon_@item.Id"></i>`

Comment: Well, the idea behind the Icon CSS in the database was that if users wanted to change the look and feel of the Menu structure, they could choose from a list of icons available on the presentation side and then change the value in the IconCssName column with interaction to the DTO using the appropriate icon name. I also have a field for SortOrder, But there has to be a more consistent and cleaner way to do something like this, right? I feel like I'm missing something or just can't see the bigger picture.

Comment: In this case then I would say you were justified in storing the class name in the database. However instead of storing the complete name I would suggest storing the icon id. So your database table of icons would simply be a title and a primary key. Then in your css file would be `.icon_1` where 1 is the primary key. This gives you the most flexiblity when it comes to changing class names as you wouldn't have go to through the database changing them.